# Creating a stickman

Tags: modeling, animation, sculpting

I'm new to Blender and I have been trying to model a stick man but maybe I can't... I've tried suching online for any videos on tutorias on how to go about it but I can't find any, I need to create such a model, but every time I try I end up with something else, for the head I can create a very smoth one from torus shape which I can create from the main cube, such that I can manupulate the internal radius not like the default tarus fron the blender add tool. If anyone can help I will be greatful... Thank you.... [image]

Comment: you can easily change the radius for the torus like this: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/63J23.gif

Answer (score 3):

You can use a circle for the head, then extrude down the vertex, use a *Mirror* modifier to mirror the shape:

[image]

Then give your object a *Skin* and a *Subdivision Surface* modifier. To thicken the limbs use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> in *Edit* mode:

[image]

Apply the *Mirror* and the *Skin* modifiers, select some edge loop and  simplify the topology with some <kbd>X</kbd> > *Limited Dissolve*:

[image]

At the end, duplicate some parts of your mesh to create the eyes and mouth:

[image]

Comment: +1 although his stickman is red :D and the eyes are rounder :D :D

Comment: @Chris mine is red as well but I'm in Solid mode!!

Comment: so you know you made a big mistake with the eyes....!? :D

Comment: You got me one more time, please don't tell anyone   :((

Comment: maybe you can update your answer with a lattice for the eyes and then a shape key to the lattice to correct that? ;D

Comment: @Chris I guess it must be doable with geonodes and I count on you for that

Comment: naaah....i don't want to steal your answer here.... :D you need it to become the No.1 :D

Comment: I wish I understood @Chris ... About the eyes.... But thanks buddy this has greatly helped me a lot ....

Comment: I wish I understood @Chris as well  ^^

Comment: Maybe @Chris was tired again 